# after deploy django project it showing this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

Tags: python, django

After move localhost to cpanel it shwoimg me that error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'**. How can I fix it? please suggest to me.

The traceback is:

```
row     [1,
 ['AC Service', 'AC Repair', 'AC Install/Uninstall'],
 ['Split AC', 'Window AC', 'Stand AC', 'Split AC with Inverter', 'No Idea'],
 'AC Repair and Service',
 'ac-repair-and-service',
 '',
 'products/slide/24/12/2020/ac-repair-2.jpg',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'For our Clients, ...',
 '',
 '',
 '2020-12-24',
 '2020-12-26']

rows    <itertools.chain object at 0x2b4cce057ee0>

self    <django.db.backends.mysql.compiler.SQLCompiler object at 0x2b4cce057bb0>

value   '2020-12-24'
```

Comment: Looks like you've got somewhere date or datetime not as `datetime` object but rather a string.

Comment: I used datetime format in the model for uploading images like that  "image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%d/%m/%Y', blank =True)"

Comment: Yeah, you have value '2020-12-24' which is string but not date and probably it's not your ImageField, but that field at the end of values list.

Comment: so, what should I do?

Comment: First, you need to determine which database field is the source of the error. Second, find the place where the wrong value is assigned.

Comment: but it working fine in my localhost

Comment: What database do you have locally? Some of them could get string values as dates by default or when configured so.

Comment: I used sqlite3 on localhost but after deploy, I converted that into MySQL

Comment: Thanks! your suggestion really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all Q&A:

- You have value `'2020-12-24'` which is string but not date `Date(2020, 12, 24)` and it's not your ImageField, but that field at the end of row values `...'2020-12-24', '2020-12-26']`.
- Locally, you have SQLite that doesn't have a Date type and consumes string value as a valid date https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype.

And the possible solutions are:

- Setup the same database locally as on your public server, MySQL in your case, to experiment further.
- Determine which field is the source of the error and find the place where wrong value is assigned.
- Convert str to valid date with `value = date.fromisoformat(value)` or `value = datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d")`.